# CakePHP 2.5 model gera JOIN em coluna que nao existe

Tags: cakephp-2

Bom dia

Estou usando cakePHP 2.5 e tenho uma tabela de veículos e uma de endereço de veículos.

Não existe a coluna veiculo_id mas é gerado um JOIN que a utiliza ao inv´s de utilizar a vei_id que foi explicitamente indicada na conditions : `'conditions' => 'VeiculoEndereco.vei_id = Veiculo.vei_id'`

Está sendo gerado de forma errada:

```
(VeiculoEndereco.veiculo_id = Veiculo.vei_id)
```

Na model do Veiculo tenho :

```
public $hasOne = array(
            'VeiculoEndereco' => array(
                'className'  => 'VeiculoEndereco',
                'type'=>'LEFT',
                'foreignkey' => 'vei_id',
                'conditions' => 'VeiculoEndereco.vei_id = Veiculo.vei_id'
            )
    );
```

E Na models do Endereço do Veiculo tenho :

```
public $belongsTo = array(
        'Veiculo' => array(
            'className' => 'Veiculo',
            'foreignKey' => 'vei_id',
            'conditions' => 'VeiculoEndereco.vei_id = Veiculo.vei_id' 
        ),);

 LEFT JOIN veiculo_enderecos VeiculoEndereco ON (VeiculoEndereco.vei_id = Veiculo.vei_id AND VeiculoEndereco.veiculo_id = Veiculo.vei_id)
```

Como posso eliminar do JOIN esta consulta com a coluna errada ? (`VeiculoEndereco.veiculo_id = Veiculo.vei_id`) e manter somente o JOIN correto (`VeiculoEndereco.vei_id = Veiculo.vei_id`) ?

Mesmo explicitamente indicando a conditions : `'conditions' => 'VeiculoEndereco.vei_id = Veiculo.vei_id'` ainda é gerada consulta por coluna que não existe : `**VeiculoEndereco.vei_id** = Veiculo.vei_id`

Comment: Talvez não tenha entendido bem tua dúvida, mas não seria somente alterar para: `VeiculoEndereco ON VeiculoEndereco.vei_id = Veiculo.vei_id`?

Comment: ele gera JOIN usando a coluna que não existe : VeiculoEndereco.veiculo_id . Somente existe vei_id abreviado. Não consigo retirar esta veiculo_id do JOIN, estou buscando como poderia retirar VeiculoEndereco.veiculo_id do JOIN